# How can I run a Ubuntu Hyper-V vm in full screen mode incl. copy between host and vm?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I created a Linux Ubuntu 17.10 vm with Hyper-V on Windows 10 (Fall Creators Update).

The integrated services like shutdown and reboot work fine but I cannot copy files between host and vm, clipboard does’t work and I cannot resize the vm windows (so I cannot run it in full screen).

A workstation vm without full screen mode is useless to me.

What configuration step or install package did I miss?

Following my configuration:

[Hyper-V Integrated Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtomO.png)

[lsmod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbQgg.png)

I also installed:

apt-get install --install-recommends linux-virtual
apt-get install linux-tools-virtual linux-cloud-tools-virtual

but that didn’t help either.

Comment: for those of us who don't  speak german - translating the first screenshot would be handy

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it just shows that all Hyper-V integrated services have been checked.

Comment: Enable enhanced session mode from Hyper-V settings.

Comment: @Biswa Sorry, forgot to mention that it is already activated.

Answer (score 2):

For the screen resolution open terminal and
sudo nohup gedit /etc/default/grub

Add resolution to this line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"

sudo update-grub

Restart and change sth in Display settings and back (e.g. Sticky edges) to avoid error

Still working on Copy/Paste
Cheers
G.

Comment: Any updates on the copy/paste issue? ;)

Answer (score 0):

To get clipboard integration to work with a Hyper-V Ubuntu VM you will need:

1. An Ubuntu OS with the Hyper-V kernel modules installed. Newer OS's have this installed by default.
   For example 22.04 LTS has these Hyper-V kernel modules:

   lsmod | grep hv_

- hv_balloon
- hv_sock
- hv_storvsc
- hv_netvsc
- hv_utils
- hv_vmbus

2. xRDP installed and configured. This allows Hyper-V to use an 'Enhanced' session instead of 'Basic' when connecting to the VM.
3. The user that will be logging in via xRDP must not already be logged in.

These install steps worked for me:

1. Create a Ubuntu 22.04 VM using 'Quick Create'.
2. After the VM is created, connect and switch to a 'Basic' session.
3. Login and then logout.
4. Switch to 'Enhanced'
5. Fill in the xRDP dialog, login should now work.

[image: Steps to 'Quick Create' the VM]

[image: Steps to switch from 'Enhanced' to 'Basic']

[image: xRDP dialog]

Comment: How do you "switch to a "basic" session?"

Comment: Click on the icon in the toolbar that looks like a little computer monitor. Depending on what mode you are presently in (Enhanced or Basic) clicking the monitor will switch you to the other mode. (See the green square in the second screen shot)

Comment: Saw your screenshot after asking. In my case it was greyed out. It turned out to be more complicated and require different steps, though I'm not sure exactly what I did to get it to function again in enhanced session mode.